# A single product url for every page - opencart

Tags: php, seo, opencart

Now the url of the product is changed based on the page you are.
For example:

If I click on category and then on product the url of the product will be:
www.mysite.com/sneakers/street/nike-air-max-v1

If I click on manufacturer and then on product the url of the product will be:
www.mysite.com/nike/nike-air-max-v1

For SEO reasons I want only a single url, the one when I click on category. 
How can I do that in opencart 1.5x ?

Comment: ok you want to add all categories under same page url. Am i right?

Comment: I wanted to remove all duplicates pages for product and to have just one url for product. www.mysite.com/category/subcategory/product-slug, I fond a solution I installed a plugin with remove all duplicates links.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using relationship canonical in head section of your website.

If you were to have these two URLs:
www.example.com/sneakers/street/nike-air-max-v1
www.example.com/nike/nike-air-max-v1

I would "choose" one main URL and then in each other URL  section write this line

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/nike/nike-air-max-v1">
```

So, at the end of the day, sneakers/street/nike-air-max-v1 page (part of) code would look like:

```
<head>
<title>Nike Air Max V1</title>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/nike/nike-air-max-v1">
</head>
```